# JSon Read inner array

Tags: java, android, json, dynamic

Hi I'm working on a dynamic android application and i have the following json. Reading each line is fine i've figured out how to do this in java (keep in mind i just started working with json yesterday) how can i read the inner array of say sample item2 to an ArrayList in java i need some kind of loop to add to a string array the screen shot links. Thank you for any help with my problem.

```
 "Manager": 
[
    { 
"name" : "Sample item", 
"icon" : "http://www.test.com/icon.png", 
"link" : "http://www.test.com/sample.zip", 
"summary" : "sample summary here", 
"screenshots": [ 
    "http://test.com/link2screenshot1.png", 
    "http://test.com/link2screenshot2.png"
    ] 
    },
    { 
"name" : "Sample item2", 
"icon" : "http://www.test.com/icon2.png", 
"link" : "http://www.test.com/sample2.zip", 
"summary" : "sample summary here2", 
"screenshots": [ 
    "http://test.com/2/link2screenshot1.png", 
    "http://test.com/2/link2screenshot2.png"
    ] 
}
]
```

**===EDIT===**

Alright here is the final solution the following method will read a json from a url and pull what i want thanks to ninetwozero

```
public ArrayList<String> JSONInner(int count, String url, String outer, String inner){
    ArrayList<String> linkArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    URL u = null;
    StringBuilder FileData = null;
    try {
        u = new URL(url);
        String InputData =       null;
        InputStream is =         null;
        DataInputStream dis =    null;
        FileData = new StringBuilder();
        is = u.openStream();
        dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(is));
        while ((InputData = dis.readLine()) != null) {
            FileData.append(InputData);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JSONObject json = null;
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(FileData.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(FileData.toString() != null) {
        try {
            JSONArray managerArray = json.getJSONArray(outer);
            JSONObject managerObject = managerArray.optJSONObject(count);
            JSONArray linkArray = managerObject.getJSONArray(inner);
            for(int subCount = 0, maxSubCount = linkArray.length(); subCount < maxSubCount; subCount++){
                linkArrayList.add( linkArray.getString( subCount ));
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return linkArrayList;
}
```

Comment: Are you doing it by hand or are you using something like jackson ? http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

Comment: @redben doing it by hand currently i can post the method i'm using to get the lines i need if that's needed, however it is messy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it the following way:

```
//Init
ArrayList<String> linkArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray managerArray = new JSONArray(yourString);

//Iterate over the top-level array
for( int count = 0, max = managerArray.length(); count < max; count++ ) {

    //Get the current JSONObject & the link array
    JSONObject managerObject = managerArray.optJSONObject(count);
    JSONArray linkArray = managerObject.getJSONArray("screenshots");

    //Iterate over the screenshots
    for( 
        int subCount = 0, maxSubCount = linkArray.length(); 
        subcount < maxSubCount; 
        subCount++ 
    ) {

        //Let's store the String
        linkArrayList.add( linkArray.getString( subCount );

    }

}
```

Let me know if this is what you're looking for. :-)

Edit: However, this would give you ALL the links - if you just want the one for array item #2, then you can remove the outer loop and declare the following:

```
int count = 0; //The 0 should be the index of your item
```

Comment: just so i'm clear managerArray = new JSONArray(yourString) would yourString be equal to say "Sample item2", Also where would i tell it the json is "Manager" or is that not needed? thank you for the reply

Comment: nevermind i assume now that JSONArray managerArray = new JSONArray(yourString) would be JSONArray managerArray = new JSONArray("Manager") and then if i wanted the second items screen shots would i set count equal to 1 since it's 0 index? although then i'd loop over the first one as well which i don't want the screen shots for?

Comment: sorry for the third comment i keep losing the ability to edit but i think i completely understand removing the loop now and gonna give it a run i'll let you know how it goes thanks

Comment: Last comment i promise :p how would I pass it the full json as well lol sorry very very new to working with json

Comment: Hey, sorry about not seeing this earlier - the "yourString" corresponds to the JSON-string in your original post - in other words, what you download from a web server. || The JSONArray is 0-indexed, so you'll have to set `int count = 1` if you were to get element #2 (without looping past #1 first). I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "pass it the whole JSON as well", as it actually handles that "as-is" right now. :-)

Comment: yea i got it all figured out working like a charm the method i made in the question for anyone else who needs it but it's perfect thanks so much!

Comment: Errm, I didn't notice that you updated your post - my bad! Glad I could help out!